# GetCount raises exception

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-9.1

I opted to use gp.GetCount in my script. This raises an exception, though the process completes "successfully" while returning zero features (which is untrue). I'm wondering how this could be. Using ArcGIS 9.1 and Python 2.1.

```
file = open(txt).read().splitlines()
for line in file:
    query = "[FIELD] = \"%s\"" % line
    if line[:].isdigit():
        gp.SelectLayerByAttribute("lyr1", "ADD_TO_SELECTION", query)
result = int(gp.getCount("lyr1").getOutput(0))

gp.Append("lyr1", "featureclass", "NO_TEST")
gp.DeleteFeatures("lyr1")
gp.SelectLayerByAttribute("lyr1", "CLEAR_SELECTION")
```

Output looks like..

```
Execution GetCount lyr1 0
Row Count = 0
Executed Successfully
```

Frankly I just want to check if my feature layer (created with makefeaturelayer) is null.

Comment: Try `query = "[FIELD] = \"%s\"" % line.strip()` -- I'm guessing there's a newline character (`\n`) at the end of each line that's causing problems.

Comment: Well something is certainly amiss since I tried running the script without the count and no features were appended or deleted in subsequent geoprocessing though it runs without errors. It's behaving as though my feature layer doesn't exist or has no features. This is with the strip too. My file is
   file = open(txt).read().splitlines()

Comment: Yeah I run MakeFeatureLayer before the loop.

Comment: Have you debugged to verify the results of your `isdigit` check for each line?

Comment: They're all digits, no blanks.

Comment: FYI gp is win32com.client, and the workspace is an SDE.

Comment: You're checking numeric values, but quoting them in the query. Is the field formatted as a string?

Comment: That is correct. Also for whatever reason adding a finally clause to my try causes a syntax error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14786/discussion-between-nmpeterson-and-sleep6).

Comment: Appreciated, I will have to get back to this tomorrow, I apologize! Thank you for the help so far.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my proposal for a more efficient method, that will perform only one query (at the time that `MakeFeatureLayer` is called):

```
field_values = []
r = open(txt, 'rb')
for line in r:
    v = line.strip()
    if v.isdigit():
        field_values.append(v)
r.close()

lyr = 'lyr1'
query = "[FIELD] IN ('%s')" % "','".join([str(v) for v in field_values])
gp.MakeFeatureLayer(INPUT_FEATURE_CLASS, lyr, query)
result = int(gp.getCount(lyr).getOutput(0))

gp.Append(lyr, 'featureclass', 'NO_TEST')
gp.DeleteFeatures(lyr)
gp.SelectLayerByAttribute(lyr, 'CLEAR_SELECTION')
```

It's been a long, long time since I wrote any Python for earlier than version 2.6, and equally long since I wrote any ArcGIS SQL statements for earlier than version 9.3, so there may be things in the above code that aren't quite right. (I don't have any way of testing in that environment, unfortunately.)

One other note: make sure your SQL is formatted appropriately for the data source -- see Esri's [SQL Reference](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.1/index.cfm?TopicName=SQL%20reference) page. The way my code above is currently formatted, *FIELD* is a text field in a personal geodatabase. Looking more closely at yours, I think you need to change the double quotes in your query to single quotes, i.e. `query = "[FIELD] = '%s'" % line`, to satisfy Esri's SQL formatting requirements.

Comment: replied in chat

Answer (score 1):

Solved. According to esri's webhelp -

"If you're querying ArcSDE geodatabase data or data in an ArcIMS feature class or ArcIMS image service sublayer, don't enclose fields"

So,

`query = "FIELD IN ('%s')" % "','".join([str(v) for v in field_values])`

There you have it. Foolish of me to overlook that. Thanks for the help.

`getCount` still interrupts the script completely, for what it's worth.